# How to test factory's success and error function from jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, promise

```
myService.loginServiceMethod(baseURL,User).success(function(userData){

           //statements;

        }).error(function(error){
           //statements;
        });
```

Above code represents that I'm calling my factory, my question is as follows:

**how to test the success and error function using jasmine.** Right now I'm able to call my factory and my other code but I'm not able to call these two function and their inside statements please help...

Comment: Can you use Mocha instead of Jasmine?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Actually I only know Jasmine for writing testcases. if you know in mocha to test this please tell may be it will give me some idea.

Comment: Mocha uses the same syntax as Jasmine, but you can `return` promises to test them. If you'd like I can add an answer using Mocha, there is also a jasmine plugin (jasmine-as-promised) which you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Your error function should throw an exception, which you can test for with the .toThrow matcher, or if you are using Jasmine 2.0 or better you can test it with the .toThrowError matcher to look for a specific exception. If you have chosen not to throw an error, just check for the values that you are returning from the error function. To test that, simply introduce conditions that will cause it to throw an error.

The Jasmine matchers are described here:

http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html

http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html